# Lagrangian mechanics VS Newtonian Mechanics for control systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, classical-mechanics, optimal-control

I have seen that a lot of people doing Lagrangian mechanics that Newtonian mechanics. But I wonder if it's better to build Langarian ODE:s insted of Newtonian ODE:s if I'm going to create models of robotic arms?

My goal is to build advanced mathematical models, such as robotic arms and system who have no and endpoint, of ODE:s and apply them into a linear control system.

I always have the issue that I need to have stiffness $k$, like a spring, in my system, or else the system will be unstable. I inverted pendulum doesn't have stiffness in the rotating center down below.

Which one is best for me then:

1. Lagrangian mechanics
2. Newtonian mechanics

I have heard that Hamiltonian mechanics is used too, but they isn't fitt for control system, right?

I appreciate for the answers.

Comment: Most of what I have read on is the neural network control of robots manipulators (arms), I can say that most papers in this area use Newtonian mechanics. I would suggest reading almost any paper Frank L. Lewis for a reference.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Lagrangian and Newtonian method should result in the same equations of motion. The only difference is how you derive them. I find that Newtonian mechanics can be a bit more intuitive, however Lagrangian mechanics is a more systematic approach and therefore less prone for errors. Especially when dealing with systems with rotational motion, like your robot arm, Newtonian mechanics can be a real pain, so I would suggest Lagrangian mechanics. But you could always do both and compare the two to be more confident about the correctness of your model.

Comment: Can Lagrangian handle forces too from velocity and displacement? Like $F = B \dot{y}(t)$ and $F = K y(t) $ Or is that only for Newtonian  mechanics?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Both can.

Comment: Is it better to add the force later to the Lagrangian equation, or should I convert $F = B\dot{y}(t)$ to kinect energy and $F = Ky(t)$ to potential energi directly?

Comment: @ But how should I convert $F = B \dot{y}(t)$ to $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $? I know that $v = \dot{y}(t)$ so can I assume that $B = \frac{1}{2}m$ ? Also when it comes to potential energy $PE = mgh$ and $F = K y(t) $. Here I can say that $mg = K$ and $h = y(t)$

Comment: Sorry! It should be $W = K y(t)$ because $W$ is the work, and also will act like a potential energy in this case.

Comment: I found the answer. If $W = B \dot{y}(t)$ then $PE = \frac{1}{2}B\dot{y}^2(t)$ and $PE = mgh = K y(t)$

Comment: I think it's better to add forces later after I have convert the Lagrangian equation to newtonian.